# Changing labelfont in longfigure captions

Tags: captions

In contrast with floats like `table` and `figure`, as well as the `longtable` environment, the caption of `longfigure` (the figure equivalent of `longtable`) does not appear in bold by default. The package documentation does not provide for options to change and working with

`\captionsetup[longfigure]{labelfont=bf}`

has no effect. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longfigure}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{My Figure has a caption that spans the entire textwidth. Exactly like I want to.}\label{fig:figure} 
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{longfigure}{cc}
\caption{My Longfigure does not have a bold label and does not span the entire tex width. What's wrong?}\label{fig:longfigure} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{6cm}{3cm} & \rule{6cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{6.3cm}{3cm} & \rule{6.3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{6cm}{3cm} & \rule{6cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{5cm}{3cm} & \rule{5cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\end{longfigure}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to work on appearance and size of the longfigure caption?

Comment: `longfigure` is no known float-type to the `caption` package, that's why it is not working for `\captionsetup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the `longfigure` package and just took a look at it. Well, it's mainly a fork of `longtable` with every `\LT@xxx` replaced by `\LF@xxx`, and of course using the `figure` counter instead of the `table` counter.

In my point of view this is the wrong approach since there are numerous document classes and packages out there which are aware of the `longtable` package and contain adaptions to it, but no-one is aware of the `longfigure` package. Instead I suggest patching `longtable` so it can use the `figure` counter as an alternative to the `table` package.

And guess what? I have already done this in 2007, and have integrated this patch into the (lt)caption package ;-)

The key is re-defining the newly offered command `\LTcaptype` which contains the counter used by `longtable`. This works with user-defined, new float types as well:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalsize}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{diagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{My Figure has a caption that spans the entire textwidth. Exactly like I want to.}\label{fig:figure} 
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\caption{My Longfigure does have a bold label and does span the entire text width.}\label{fig:longfigure} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{5cm}{3cm} & \rule{5cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\end{longtable}

\renewcommand\LTcaptype{diagram}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\caption{My Longdiagram does have a bold label and does span the entire text width.}\label{fig:longdiagram} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{5cm}{3cm} & \rule{5cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

(This is a documented feature, unfortunately it's not mentioned in the `caption` package documentation (yet) but in the `ltcaption` package documentation instead.)

If you prefer having a separate `longfigure` environment this could be easily defined by

```
\newenvironment{longfigure}
  {\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}\longtable}
  {\endlongtable}
```

The complete example document, modified:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalsize}

\newenvironment{longfigure}
  {\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}\longtable}
  {\endlongtable}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{diagram}
\newenvironment{longdiagram}
  {\renewcommand\LTcaptype{diagram}\longtable}
  {\endlongtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{My Figure has a caption that spans the entire textwidth. Exactly like I want to.}\label{fig:figure} 
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{longfigure}{cc}
\caption{My Longfigure does have a bold label and does span the entire text width.}\label{fig:longfigure} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{5cm}{3cm} & \rule{5cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\end{longfigure}

\begin{longdiagram}{cc}
\caption{My Longdiagram does have a bold label and does span the entire text width.}\label{fig:longdiagram} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{5cm}{3cm} & \rule{5cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{4cm}{3cm} & \rule{4cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{3cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
\rule{1cm}{3cm} & \rule{1cm}{3cm} \\
\end{longdiagram}

\end{document}
```