# How to define reference label and caption name in 'duplicated' environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, environments, counters, labels

I want to define a new environment that is very similar to the longtable environment, therefore I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}


%% Defining the examplebox environment
\definecolor{examplebox}{gray}{0.95} %define the examplebox color
\newcounter{examplebox}
\newcommand*{\exampleboxautorefname}{Example box}
\newenvironment{examplebox}{
    \refstepcounter{examplebox}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}
    \renewcommand*\tablename{Example box}‌\longtable
}{\endlongtable}

\begin{document}
\autoref{box:test} is the label of this examplebox.\\

The current counter for examplebox is \theexamplebox.

\begin{examplebox}{|c|} \hline
    \rowcolor{examplebox} Hello there.\\ \hline
    \caption{Caption of this example box.}
    \label{box:test}
\end{examplebox}

The current counter for examplebox is now \theexamplebox.

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| c c c |}
            \hline
        1&2&3\\ \hline
        4&5&6\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Random table caption}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

The current counter for examplebox is still \theexamplebox.

\end{document}
```

This gives the caption 'Examplebox 0: Caption of this example box.'. After the examplebox, the counter has increased to 1, so the counter of examplebox seems to work. However, the environment folows the Table counter, and using \autoref gives 'Table 0' instead of 'Example box 0'.

How can I get examplebox to use the defined counter and to include this in the autoref command? Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks in advance!

Tim

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could make it slightly easier for people to help you if you did not only show code snippets, but a [full compilable example that people can just copy, paste and run](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32553/35864 together with your `refstepcounter` you are already there if you can convince `longtable` to take the counter value of `examplebox` inszead of it the table counter. But maybe there is a more elegant method.

Comment: Maybe `ltcaption`'s `\LTcaptype`  or `longtable*` can also help you...

Comment: I'm not sure if that is only the example from your question, but there arme more elegant ways to obtain a box than `longtable`. `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` spring to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I will upload a full compilable example next time. LTcaption could work, but I also have 'normal' longtables in the same document... But that still doesn't solve the problem regarding cross-referencing to the example box, does it?

Comment: If applied correctly `\LTcaption` can be made to apply only to your `examplebox` and it would also solve the referencing problem if done properly I believe. I would investigate further, but I can't really be bothered to guess your code snippets into a fully compilable document...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will dive into the LTcaption package, if I cant manage to solve it, I will upload a full compilable example.

Comment: If you do manage to solve be sure to post an answer so other people can benefit from this.

Comment: Once upon a time I wrote a `longfigure` package but never released it. I will see if I still get the source since you only need to rename `longfigure` to `examplebox` to have a solution. Please hold the line...

Comment: Of course I will share a potential solution, or any progress towards it @moewe.

Comment: Can I post a compilable example as an answer? Or how do I do this without creating a new post?

Comment: Edit your question to add an example. Only answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: @TimvanDam Found it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327649/2574 (Originating from http://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/JrzmR00d/use-of-longtable-as-longfigure ) The funny thing: The answer below already uses this approach. It seems I lost track of all the LaTeX things I have done in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example it looks as though `examplebox` is just a box with coloured background in which case dedicated box packages like [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or [`framed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/framed) might be a better choice than a self-made `longtable` environment.

Anyway, `ltcaption`'s `\LTcaptype` looked promising. To be able to use it I we can define a new float type with help of the `newfloat` package. `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{examplebox}` already defines a new counter and the environment, so that we only need to redefine it for `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{examplebox}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{examplebox}[Example box][List of example boxes]
\newcommand*{\exampleboxautorefname}{Example box}
\renewenvironment{examplebox}{%
   \renewcommand\LTcaptype{examplebox}%
   \longtable}
  {\endlongtable}

\begin{document}
\autoref{box:test} is the label of this examplebox.

The current counter for examplebox is \theexamplebox.

\begin{examplebox}{|c|} \hline
    \rowcolor{examplebox} Hello there.\\ \hline
    \caption{Caption of this example box.}
    \label{box:test}
\end{examplebox}

The current counter for examplebox is now \theexamplebox.

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| c c c |}
            \hline
        1&2&3\\ \hline
        4&5&6\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Random table caption}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

The current counter for examplebox is still \theexamplebox.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The examplebox should be able to break over multiple pages. Furthermore, I'm editing a book that contains over 100 example boxes currently written witt the the longtable environment. This slight modification seemed the easiest way to change the reference label to Example box. Thanks again!

Comment: @TimvanDam `tcolorbox` can have its boxes broken across pages as well, so that should not be a problem. Of course converting things to a new, cleaner syntax may take a bit of time. Sometimes it pays off, sometimes it doesn't. But please keep it in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `longtable`

- makes use of the `table`-counter.
- causes the `\caption`-command to write entries for the list of tables (the .lot-file) and to make use of the `table`-counter.

These aspects are "hard-wired" both into the `longtable` environment and into the patch for the `longtable`-environment provided by the  **hyperref** package.

In other words:
Unfortunately there is no `\usecounter` and no `\uselistof` for `longtable`-environments.

With your example-boxes you might wish

- to use another counter than the `table`-counter
- not to have entries for example-boxes merged into the list of tables but to have a separate list of example boxes.

As things are somewhat "hardwired" in the **longtable**-package, if you want to be accurate, you need to derive your own style-file/your own package, containing your own variant of the `longtable`-environment where each occurrence of the usage of the `table`-counter is replaced by usage of the `examplebox`-counter, and where each attempt at writing to the .lot-file is replaced by attempts at writing to the list-of-exampleboxes-file (.loEB-file in the example below).
That package should also take into account patches as provided by the **hyperref**-package.

If you don't wish to be accurate, you can within the `examplebox`-environment

- redirect using the infrastructure of the `table`-counter to using the infrastructure of the `examplebox`-counter. Be aware that macros like `\hyper@makecurrent`, which use the counter-name directly for deriving names of anchors for hyperlinks, need to be patched so that they crank out the usage of the name of the `table`-counter and replace it by usage of the name of the `examplebox`-counter.
- redirect writing to the .lot-file to writing to another file, e.g., to a .loEB-file. In order to achieve this, the macro `\addcontentsline` can be patched to crank out cases where entries shall go to the .lot-file / the `\ext@table`-file.

**Spontaneously I see two important reasons why this redirection-approach is not accurate:**

1. This redirection-approach breaks nesting inside your `examplebox`-environment things other than `examplebox`-environments that also use the `table`-counter and/or that also write entries for the list of tables/for the .lot-file.
2. This redirection-approach might break `\autoref`erencing tables and other things where the `table`-counter was used for creating the corresponding referencing-label for cases where the auto-reference is to occur/to take place "inside" the `examplebox`-environment.

**Thus a rule of thumb: With the code below don't nest tables and other things that make use of the `table`-counter or that do write to the list of tables inside the `examplebox`-environment.**

In case you can live with this, here is some code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
%% Use examplebox-stuff instead of table-stuff:
%%
%% Inside the examplebox-environment
%%
%% - \hyper@makecurrent needs to redirect using the table-counter 
%%   to using the examplebox-counter. The following things are needed
%%   for patching \hyper@makecurrent inside the examplebox environment:
\newcommand\MySavedhyper@makecurrent{}%
\AtBeginDocument{\let\MySavedhyper@makecurrent=\hyper@makecurrent}%
\newcommand\Mytablestring{table}%
\newcommand\MyPatchedhyper@makecurrent[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \long\def\@tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\@tempa\Mytablestring
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\MySavedhyper@makecurrent{examplebox}}%
  {\MySavedhyper@makecurrent{#1}}%
}%
%% - \addcontentsline needs to redirect writing to the lot-file
%%   to writing to the loEB-file (list of Example Boxes).
%%   The following things are needed for patching \addcontentsline
%%   inside the examplebox environment:
\newcommand\MySavedAddcontentsline{}%
\AtBeginDocument{\let\MySavedAddcontentsline=\addcontentsline}%
\newcommand\Mylotstring{lot}%
\newcommand\Mylotstringb{\csname ext@table\endcsname}%
\newcommand\MyPatchedAddcontentsline[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \long\def\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\Mylotstring
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {%
    \ifx\@tempa\Mylotstringb
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
    {\endgroup\MySavedAddcontentsline{#1}}%
  }%
  {\endgroup\MySavedAddcontentsline{loEB}}%
}%
%%
%% \ExampleboxStuffInsteadOfTableStuff performs redirecting and patching.
%% 
\newcommand\ExampleboxStuffInsteadOfTableStuff{%
  % Redirect LaTeX 2e-kernel-counter-infrastructure-stuff of 
  % the table counter to the examplebox counter
  \let\c@table=\c@examplebox
  \let\thetable=\theexamplebox
  \let\p@table=\p@examplebox
  \let\cl@table=\cl@examplebox
  % Redirect hyperref-counter-infrastructure-stuff and \autoref-stuff
  % of the table counter to the examplebox counter:
  \let\theHtable=\theHexamplebox
  % \let\tableautorefname=\exampleboxautorefname
  \let\tablename=\exampleboxname %<- in case \tableautorefname is undefined, 
                                 %   this will break \autoref-erencing tables
                                 %   inside the examplebox-environment!
  % patch for hyperref's longtable patch =
  % patch \hyper@makecurrent to crank out usage of the table-counter:
  \let\hyper@makecurrent=\MyPatchedhyper@makecurrent
  % patch \addcontentsline to crank out usage of lot:
  \let\addcontentsline=\MyPatchedAddcontentsline
}%

%% examplebox environment
%%
\definecolor{examplebox}{gray}{0.95} %define the examplebox color
\newcounter{examplebox}
\newcommand*{\exampleboxautorefname}{Example box}
\newcommand*{\exampleboxname}{Example box}
\newcommand*\listexampleboxname{List of example boxes}%
\newenvironment{examplebox}{%
   \ExampleboxStuffInsteadOfTableStuff
   \longtable
}{\endlongtable}

%% \listofexampleboxes
%%
\newcommand\listofexampleboxes{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue
    \onecolumn
  \else 
    \@restonecolfalse 
  \fi 
  \chapter*{\listexampleboxname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listexampleboxname}%
          {\MakeUppercase\listexampleboxname}%
  \@starttoc{loEB}%
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftables\newpage

\listofexampleboxes\newpage

\autoref{box:test} is the label of this examplebox.\\

The current counter for examplebox is \theexamplebox.

% A column of type p{<width>} from the array package is 
% used to make enumerate and itemize work.
\begin{examplebox}{|p{5cm}|} \hline
    \rowcolor{examplebox}%
    \label{box:test}%
    \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \end{enumerate}
     Hello there.\\ \hline
    \caption{Caption of this example box.}
\end{examplebox}

The current counter for examplebox is now \theexamplebox.

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| c c c |}
            \hline
        1&2&3\\ \hline
        4&5&6\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Random table caption}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

The current counter for examplebox is still \theexamplebox.

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this proposed solution. However, I cannot manage to use enumerate inside this environment, while itemize does not give any problems... Do you have any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @TimvanDam There was a bug in `\MyPatchedhyper@makecurrent`:  Instead of `\expandafter@secondoftwo` it must be `\expandafter\@secondoftwo` My apologies. I've edited my answer accordingly. Besides this: For `itemize` and `enumerate` I suggest loading the `array` package and using `p{<width>}` columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks even better now. Only I also want the reference label to be 'Example box 1' instead of 'item 1' (top of page 3). This problem only arises when enumerate is used inside the examplebox environment, while itemize works fine... I've searched everywhere and even tried to modify the autoref function, but I didn't get this to work.

Comment: @TimvanDam You can probably also do something like `\multicolumn{1}{p{5cm}}{\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}...\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate]}` Also be aware that the label for the box must come before any other counter is incremented via`\refstepcounter` as is the case e.g. with `enumerate`.

Comment: @TimvanDam Inside your examplebox place the referencing-label somewhere where yet no other counter is incremented via `\refstepcounter`. `enumerate` does use `\refstepcounter` and thus does change the info that goes into following referencing-labels. I overlooked that. I just edited my answer so that it shows correct `\label`-placement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @UlrichDiez! Actually the top answer of @moewe gives me what I want already, apart from the 'right' reference label, which is, as you mentioned, just a matter of defining the label before starting the enumeration. I posted a seperate [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441904/how-to-prevent-reference-to-enumeration-inside-new-environment), which you helped me solve with this answer right here.