# Reference for \newlabel

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160035/30052) it is mentioned that `hyperref` overwrites `\newlabel` and therefore if one loads the package it requires six (rather than two) arguments. I was trying to learn the syntax of `\newlabel`, with and without `hyperref`, but in the documentation PDF [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) I found nothing. Can someone point to a reference where I can read and learn how these commands work?

Comment: In my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714)  to the question ["How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/441904/118714) I tried to explain [the concepts related to cross-referencing in LaTeX 2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714). Perhaps this is of interest to you.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you so much, I have gone through your answer, which is really awesome and complete.

Answer (score 8):

The statement that `\newlabel` requires six arguments under [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) compared to the default two is not correct. `hyperref` still only uses a two-argument `\newlabel`, but rather puts five arguments inside the second; the default is to pack only two elements in the second argument...

To see this in better detail, consider the difference in how `\label` is defined, since it ultimately writes a `\newlabel` to the `.aux` file; here's a view of the traditional `\label` (from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
def\label#1{%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\newlabel{#1}{%
      {\@currentlabel}%
      {\thepage}%
    }}%
  \@esphack}
```

A call to `\label{<label>}` will write `\newlabel{<label>}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}` in the `.aux` (resolving for `\@currentlabel` and `\thepage` to whatever the current label and it's page representation should be). As a consequence, `\ref{<label>}` will return the stored `\@currentlabel` (via a `\@firstoftwo` call) while `\pageref{<label>}` will return the stored `\thepage` (via a `\@secondoftwo` call).

Now let's look at `\label` when loading `hyperref` (inside [`nameref.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/nameref.dtx)):

```
\def\label#1{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \def\label@name{#1}%
    \label@hook
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#1}{%
        {\@currentlabel}%
        {\thepage}%
        {\@currentlabelname}%
        {\@currentHref}{}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}%
```

Now a call to `\label{<label>}` will write `\newlabel{<label>}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}` to the `.aux`. Note that the first two elements are similar to the traditional `\label`. It's the addition of three more elements (the last of which is purposefully left empty `{}`) that makes the difference. The latter discussion is briefly mentioned in the [`nameref`](//ctan.org/pkg/nameref) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/nameref) (section **3 Implementation**).

Since `hyperref` now has to deal with extraction of the elements from a 5-set, if defines `\@firstoffive`, `\@secondoffive`, ..., `\@fifthoffive`.

Ultimately, `\newlabel` in the traditional and `hyperref` sense only work with two arguments. It's just that the second argument is comprised of more elements when using `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks, this is all very clear. Can you add a couple of words on why "the last element is purposefully left empty"? Also, I see you are in British Columbia, do you teach some (advanced?) LaTeX class here?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo The purpose is to have the possibility of a fifth data-field. A fifth data-field is needed in case of importing referencing-labels from other documents (more accurate: from other documents' aux-files) by means of the xr-hyper-package. When doing this, this fifth data-field holds information about the URL where the document whose referencing-labels are imported can be found.[The comments in xr-hyper.sty might be of interest](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/xr-hyper.sty) Especially the comment below `\providecommand*{\XR@addURL}[1]{#1}`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Wow, I see. I won't use that field for a while, then, while I learn more basic stuff. But thank you very much for the precise reference.

Comment: Is it possible to set newlabel to work with hyperref?

Comment: @user3236841: Sure. What are you trying to do?