# Creating my own labels for crossreferencing

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to create a table of references. The problem is, of course, that \label gives me the section number, but I have several items in the same section that I want to reference. Is there some way to define my own labels? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
See project\label{p.1}\ref{p.1}
See project\label{p.2}\ref{p.2}

\section{Second}
See project\label{p.3}\ref{p.3}
See project\label{p.4}\ref{p.4}

\section{Tables}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Project & Link\\
\ref{p.1} & xxx\\
\ref{p.2} & yyy\\
\ref{p.3} & zzz\\
\ref{p.4} & uuu\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can put labels anywhere. What exactly do you want to appear when you reference it? Are you looking for `\pageref`?
And what do you want to achieve with referencing the label just right where it is? (in your sections First and Second)

Comment: you say `of course` `\label` produces a section number but it only does that as you have placed it after `\section` you can `\label` and `\ref` any numbered latex construct such as tables, list items etc,  however it is totally unclear what output you expect from the code shown, I would guess that  `\label{p.1}\ref{p.1}` should be simply `\ref{p.1}` to reference the items and your table should be a `\begin{itemize}` with numbered items with eg `\item\label{p.1}`  so that the ref refers to this item. (It is normally bad style to use numbers in label and ref keys)

Comment: Clarification: The elements are _not_ contained in an environment like itemize. Scattered through the text I want "See project n" where n is incremented as it appears. Then I want an appendix listing all the projects and links to them. Counters would be great for incrementing n but I can't see any way to "construct" a label from a counter. (The numbers in the label are just to give a minimal example; I am using better keys.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the macro `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` for incrementing a counter, then `\the⟨counter⟩` of the incremented counter will be available for `\label`.

You can use the hyperref package for having hyperlinks in your document.

Perhaps this is what you are after? :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{project}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
See \refstepcounter{project}project~\theproject\label{p.1}
See \refstepcounter{project}project~\theproject\label{p.2}

\section{Second}
See \refstepcounter{project}project~\theproject\label{p.3}
See \refstepcounter{project}project~\theproject\label{p.4}

\section{Tables}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Project & Link\\
\ref*{p.1} & \hyperref[p.1]{xxx}\\
\ref*{p.2} & \hyperref[p.2]{yyy}\\
\ref*{p.3} & \hyperref[p.3]{zzz}\\
\ref*{p.4} & \hyperref[p.4]{uuu}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you are interested in how cross-referencing is implemented in LaTeX: I tried to explain the basic concepts related to LaTeX's cross-referencing mechanism in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714) to the question ["How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/441904/118714).

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich! I can't remember if I ever used \refstepcounter in 30-odd years of working with LaTeX, but it is never too late to learn something new.

Comment: @Moti Learn something else: Mark Ulrich's answer as good and give it an upvote, too!