# Is my new command incompatible with hyperref?

Tags: macros, errors, hyperref

I have this command that works fine:

```
\newcommand{\mytag}[2]{%
    \text{#1}%
    \@bsphack
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\newlabel{#2}{{#1}{\thepage}}}%
    \@esphack   
}
```

but when I add the package hyperref as:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=page,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=blue,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}
```

Then latex prompts me this error when I'm using my newcommand and does not compile. The error is:

> Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.

I tried to remove all the .aux files but the error does not dissapear. It only dissapears when I comment the hyperref lines. How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [english] {babel}
\usepackage {anysize}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage {amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} %If you comment this, it works. If you uncomment it doesn't

\makeatletter

%my command
\newcommand{\mytag}[2]{%
    \text{#1}%
    \@bsphack
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\newlabel{#2}{{#1}{\thepage}}}%
    \@esphack   
}

%frougon command. It does not work as expected. It loses the posibility to refer to portions of the equations.
%\newcommand*{\mytag}[2]{\text{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myeq}
    E=\underbrace{\underbrace{mv^2}_{\mytag{kinetic}{eq:myeq_kinetic}}+\underbrace{mgh}_{\mytag{potential}{eq:myeq_potential}}}_{\mytag{total Energy}{eq:myeq_totalE}}, 
\end{equation}

Eq. \ref{eq:myeq} is the expresion for \ref{eq:myeq_totalE}, which is composed by \ref{eq:myeq_kinetic} and \ref{eq:myeq_potential} energies.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should show a complete example that can be tested, not only some snippets. With hyperref `\newlabel` needs an extended syntax: `\newlabel{a}{{1}{1}{ab}{section.1}{}}`

Comment: unrelated but `\@bsphack\@esphack` can not do anything following `\text{}`

Comment: Hi @Learning from master and welcome to TeX-SE. As said before, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133). As thumb rule, load `hyperref` last, see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/140133).

Comment: I explained the concepts related to cross-referencing in LaTeX 2e with and without hyperref in [my answer to the question "How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714). There you can read about the differences when using/not using hyperref. Beside this: If you wish to make up your own cross-referencing-mechanism independent from the LaTeX 2e-kernel and hyperref, [Heiko Oberdiek's zref-package might be of interest](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) to you. By the way: amsmath-things tend to override kernel-things like `\label`/`\ref`.

Comment: BTW, you meed \makeatletter and \makeatother around any code using @ symbols in macro names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hyperref` redefines a few LaTeX commands, including `\label`. Indeed, it needs to store more data associated to each label in the `.aux` file, in order to provide the features it offers.

Your command is essentially `\text{#1}` followed by the definition of the `\label` command from the LaTeX kernel. Thus, it writes data to the `.aux` file in a format that is incompatible with `hyperref`. In order to avoid such compatibility problems, the easiest way is to simply use `\label` to do the delicate work (the one that has to be different according to whether `hyperref` is loaded or not). Since the definition of `\label` in the LaTeX kernel is:

```latex
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

and since `amsmath` also renames `\label` to `\ltx@label`, your command can be translated as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mytag}[2]{\text{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\ltx@label{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:myeq}
    E = \underbrace{
          \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} mv^2}_{\mytag{kinetic}{eq:myeq_kinetic}}
        + \underbrace{mgh}_{\mytag{potential}{eq:myeq_potential}}
        }_{\mytag{mechanical energy}{eq:myeq_mechanicalE}}
\end{equation}

Eq.~\ref{eq:myeq} is the expression for~\ref{eq:myeq_mechanicalE}, which is
composed of~\ref{eq:myeq_kinetic} and~\ref{eq:myeq_potential} energies.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: as @DavidCarlisle [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531539/is-my-new-command-incompatible-with-hyperref/531543#comment1343988_531539), your `\@bsphack` ... `\@esphack` pair was useless in math mode.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I get this error: "Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:myeq' will be lost. ...{eq:myeq1}}+piece of equation}". The idea is to have different brackets that take some part of the equation, and print there a text and be able to refer to this portion with a label. The text is printed with yours, but then I lose the label. I'll put some of my code in my first message now.

Comment: My code showed that it worked within `$ ... $`. Part of the problem is that, as Ulrike
[pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531539/is-my-new-command-incompatible-with-hyperref/531543#comment1343984_531539), you (at first) didn't provide a minimal working example—not even
*any* example. Therefore, you didn't help me test the new command in all
relevant conditions. Not only does `hyperref` redefine `\label`, `amsmath`
also does so; I know a few things, but not everything! I have updated the answer. It works both within `$ ... $` and in the `equation` environment.

Comment: Note: the example you added is
not minimal; please don't include irrelevant packages, it only obscures the
question and makes it harder to find via search engines. Also, I modified your formula because it would be incorrect, AFAICT, without the 1/2 factor.