# How does `\autoref` (from the package hyperref) know what type of labels I am referring to?

Tags: macros, hyperref, sourcecode

I have been digging the source code of `\autoref` for quite a while, but haven't understood the way `\autoref` determines the types of labels.

I am sort of lost in the relevant code (`hyperref.dtx` line 13400-13474):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\autoref}{%
  \leavevmode
  \@ifstar{\HyRef@autoref\@gobbletwo}{\HyRef@autoref\hyper@@link}%
}
\def\HyRef@autoref#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \expandafter\HyRef@autosetref\csname r@#2\endcsname{#2}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\def\HyRef@autosetref#1#2#3{% link command, csname, refname
  \HyRef@ShowKeysRef{#2}%
  \ifcase 0\ifx#1\relax 1\fi\ifx#1\Hy@varioref@undefined 1\fi\relax
    \edef\HyRef@thisref{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }%
    \expandafter\HyRef@testreftype\HyRef@thisref.\\%
    \Hy@safe@activesfalse
    #3{%
      \expandafter\@fifthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \HyRef@currentHtag
      \expandafter\@firstoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
      \null
    }%
  \else
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    \@latex@warning{%
      Reference `#2' on page \thepage\space undefined%
    }%
  \fi
}
```

I believe `\HyRef@currentHtag` would be the tag name (e.g.`chapter`, `section`, etc.), but I don't understand how this block of code works.

What does `\csname r@#2\endcsname` (expanded to `\r@#2`) do? Is `#2` here the label (e.g. `chap:1` defined by `\label{chap:1}`)

Answer (score 3):

The story begins with `\refstepcounter`, then follows `\label` and `.aux` file, finally ends with reference commands like `\ref` or `\autoref`.

In LaTeX2e format (in a simplified form),

- `\refstepcounter{<counter>}` steps `<counter>` and then stores (or updates) its value in `\@currentlabel`.
- `\label{<key>}` writes  `\newlabel{<key>}{{<value of \@currentlabel>}{<value of \thepage}}` to `.aux` file, in which a link between label key and reference contents is established.
- When `.aux` is input in `\begin{document}`, `\newlabel` is expanded and it defines `\r@<key>` to `{<value of \@currentlabel>}{<value of \thepage}`.
- At the end, `\ref{<key>}` and `\pageref{<key>}` gets `<value of \@currentlabel>` and `<value of \thepage}` linked to `<key>`, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% 3. at second running, .aux file is input and 
%    \r@key is defined to be "{3}{1}"

section \ref{key}
% 4. get 3 from \r@key and output 3

\setcounter{section}{2}
\section{title}
% 1. now \@currentlabel is 3

\label{key} % current page is 1
% 2. now \newlabel{key}{{2}{1}} is written to .aux file
\end{document}
```

`hyperref` extends the `<key> -> <value>, <page>` link to `<key> -> <value>, <page>, <name>, <hyper ref>, <file>`. Using the above example,

- now `\section{<name>}` (which calls `\refstepcounter`) updates `\@currentlabel` to 3, `\@currentlabelname` to `<name>` (which is "title"), and `\@currentHref` to `<hyper ref>` (which is "section.3", in the form of `<counter name>.<counter value>). Note that the counter name is contained in``.
- now `\label{key}` writes `\newlabel{key}{{3}{1}{title}{section.13}{}}` to `.aux` file
- now input `.aux` file defines `\r@key` to `{3}{1}{title}{section.13}{}`.
- now `\ref` and `\pageref` acts like before, and `\nameref{<key>}` gets `<name>` (which is "title" in our example), `\autoref{<key>}` gets the combination of `<autoref name per counter> <value>` (which is "section 3").

PS:

- `\nameref` is provided by `nameref` package, which is distributed and auto loaded with `hyperref`.
- Suppose `#2` is "key", then `\csname r@#2\endcsname` expands to control sequence `\r@key` in one step of expansion. You can learn more about `\csname ... \endcsname` in docs like *TeX by Topic*.

Comment: Hi there! Muzi you are everywhere answering questions enthusiastically! I am reading your answer.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer! May I ask one more question? Is there a book for LaTeX equivalent to The TeXbook for Knuth TeX?

Comment: @Frank I'm afraid not. TeX engines (like knuth tex, pdftex, xetex, and luatex) and their backends (like dvips and dvipdfm-x) are relatively stable (and centralized), while the development of LaTeX packages and utilities are more active (and decentralized). _The LaTeX Companion_, 2nd edition is _the_ book matches your requirement when it published in 2004. Today you can still use it to learn the basic concepts in LaTeX2e format and how to config each part of a document, or waiting for its [third edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0134658949/) which is still under preparation.

Comment: @Frank For an intro to LaTeX2e format and the standard document classes, take a look at https://latexref.xyz/.

Comment: Thanks, muzimuzhi Z!

Comment: In my answer to the question [How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714) I tried to explain the mechanisms that underlie cross-referencing. With hyperref the data-structure of cross-referencing-labels contains one element which delivers the name of the destination for hyperlinking. That name usually is made up from the name and the value of the counter incremented via `\refstepcounter` as the last one before placing `label{...}`. `\autoref` from this element retrieves info about which LaTeX-counter's value is referred to.