# \labelcref doesn't like my user-defined command

Tags: macros, labels, cleveref

I have defined my own command allowing me to number and reference a single line in a starred multiline equation environment, rather than using an un-starred environment and entering `\nonumber` at the end of every other line. The command is this: `\newcommand{\TAG}[1]{\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{#1}}`

Then, I'm using `\labelcref` to reference multiple equations with a single command. For equations labelled the 'usual' way (with `\label`), the command works as expected; they are always printed in numerical order regardless of the order they are referenced in.

However, I run into problems when I use `\labelcref` for equations labelled using `\TAG`. Essentially, the references aren't ordered numerically anymore; usual `\label` references are printed first, in numerical order, and then any `\TAG` references are printed, in the order they're referenced. `labelcref` also doesn't include `\TAG` equations when printing (x) to (y), even when they are the last equations, numerically.

The examples in my MWE show what I mean. Hopefully.

I'd rather use my command once than use `\nonumber` many times, especially for environments with lots of lines. How might I get it to work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newcommand{\TAG}[1]{\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{e:test1}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test2}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test3}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test4}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\verb+\labelcref+ gives `\labelcref{e:test3,e:test4,e:test2,e:test1}' no matter the order, because \verb+\label+ is used every time \ding{51}

\begin{align*}
    y &= x + x\\
    &= 2x\TAG{e:test5}
\end{align*}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test6}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\verb+\labelcref+ gives `\labelcref{e:test5,e:test6}' no matter the order, because test5 uses \verb+\TAG+ and so it always goes last \ding{55}

\begin{align*}
    y &= x + x\\
    &= 2x\TAG{e:test7}
\end{align*}
\begin{gather*}
    y = x + x\\
    \Rightarrow y = 2x\TAG{e:test8}
\end{gather*}
\verb+\labelcref{e:test8,e:test7}+ gives `\labelcref{e:test8,e:test7}', while \verb+\labelcref{e:test7,e:test8}+ gives `\labelcref{e:test7,e:test8}'; since both equations use \verb+\TAG+, the order of reference is printed \ding{55}

\begin{equation}\label{e:test9}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{gather*}
    y = x + x\\
    \Rightarrow y = 2x\TAG{e:test10}
\end{gather*}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test11}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\verb+\labelcref+ gives `\labelcref{e:test9,e:test11,e:test10}' no matter the order; the two \verb+\label+ equations get printed first, in numerical order, and then the \verb+\TAG+ equation is printed last \ding{55}

\begin{equation}\label{e:test12}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test13}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test14}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{gather*}
    y = x + x\\
    \Rightarrow y = 2x\TAG{e:test15}
\end{gather*}
\verb+\labelcref+ gives `\labelcref{e:test12,e:test14,e:test15,e:test13}' no matter the order; the \verb+\TAG+ equation doesn't get included in the `to' \ding{55}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-referencing basically works as follows:

Commands like `\section`, `\subsection` etc internally call a macro whose name is `\refstepcounter`. This macro increments the associated counter and redefines macros whose names begin with `\@current...`, e.g., `\@currentlabel`, `\@currentHref`, etc. The purpose of these `\@current...`-macros is to always hold some piece of data wich belongs to that item of sectioning whose counter was incremented via `\refstepcounter` as the last one. The command `\label` places entries of the form `\newlabel...` into the .aux-file and hereby uses the expansion of these `\@current...`-macros for providing the data wich belongs to that item of sectioning whose counter was incremented via `\refstepcounter` as the last one. In the next LaTeX-run the .aux-file is read at the beginning and macros `\r@<name of referencing label>` get defined from these `\newlabel`-entries. Referencing-commands like `\ref` in turn expand these `\r@<name of referencing label>`-macros and from the expansion extract the piece of data they need.

I tried to elaborate in detail on the cross-referencing-mechanism of LaTeX 2e in my answer to the question "[How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714)"

---

cleveref uses its own mechanism for writing data for its own referencing-labels that are needed for internal purposes to the .aux-file in terms of `\newlabel`-entries.

Usually that mechanism ensures that (benath other things) the value of the counter that was incremented via `\refstepcounter` as the last one "is placed into the definition" of the macro `\cref@currentlabel` which in turn is used by the cleveref-package for writing a `\newlabel`-entry for internal purposes into the .aux-file.

Hereby cleveref needs to handle situations where no counter is associated. By default this is the case with environments like `align*` and `gather*`. With such environments cleveref redefines the macros `\make@df@tag@@` and `\make@df@tag@@@`, which internally are called by amsmath's `\tag`-command, in a way which leads to cleveref's `\cref@currentlabel` delivering a default-value which causes cleveref, when doing things like `\labelcref`, to treat that reference in special ways when forming/calculating the phrases for ranges of references of the same type.

When you look at the .aux-file which results from compiling your example, you find this:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{e:test1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test1@cref}{{[equation][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test2}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test2@cref}{{[equation][2][]2}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test3}{{3}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test3@cref}{{[equation][3][]3}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test4}{{4}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test4@cref}{{[equation][4][]4}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test5}{{{5}}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test5@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{5}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test6}{{6}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test6@cref}{{[equation][6][]6}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test7}{{{7}}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test7@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{7}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test8}{{{8}}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test8@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{8}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test9}{{9}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test9@cref}{{[equation][9][]9}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test10}{{{10}}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test10@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{10}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test11}{{11}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test11@cref}{{[equation][11][]11}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test12}{{12}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test12@cref}{{[equation][12][]12}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test13}{{13}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test13@cref}{{[equation][13][]13}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test14}{{14}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test14@cref}{{[equation][14][]14}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test15}{{{15}}{1}}
\newlabel{e:test15@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{15}}{[1][1][]1}}
```

The entries

```
\newlabel{e:test5@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{5}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test7@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{7}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test8@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{8}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test10@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{10}}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{e:test15@cref}{{[equation][2147483647][]{15}}{[1][1][]1}}
```

are definitely not correct in your scenario (where inside environments like `align*` and `gather*` you wish the equation-counter to be associated rather than no counter being associated) and they come from what cleveref does when the `\tag`-command is carried out within environments `align*` and `gather*`.

You can resolve this by redefining these macros in a way where they deliver data to `\cref@currentlabel` in the same way as is done for references of type "equation".

Perhaps like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
%\usepackage{showlabels}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\my@make@df@tag@@[1]{%
  \cref@old@make@df@tag@@{#1}%
  \let\cref@old@df@tag\df@tag
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\df@tag\expandafter{%
    \cref@old@df@tag
    \def\cref@currentlabel{%
      [equation][\theequation][]#1%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand*\my@make@df@tag@@@[1]{%
  \cref@old@make@df@tag@@@{#1}%
  \let\cref@old@df@tag\df@tag
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\df@tag\expandafter{%
    \cref@old@df@tag
    \toks@\@xp{\p@equation{#1}}%
    \edef\cref@currentlabel{[equation][\theequation][]\the\toks@}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand{\TAG}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \begingroup
  \let\make@df@tag@@\my@make@df@tag@@
  \let\make@df@tag@@@\my@make@df@tag@@@
  \tag{\theequation}%
  \endgroup
  \label{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{e:test1}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test2}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test3}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test4}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\verb+\labelcref{e:test3,e:test4,e:test2,e:test1}+ yields `\labelcref{e:test3,e:test4,e:test2,e:test1}' \ding{51}

\begin{align*}
    y &= x + x\\
    &= 2x\TAG{e:test5}
\end{align*}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test6}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\verb+\labelcref{e:test5,e:test6}+ yields `\labelcref{e:test5,e:test6}' \ding{51}

\begin{align*}
    y &= x + x\\
    &= 2x\TAG{e:test7}
\end{align*}
\begin{gather*}
    y = x + x\\
    \Rightarrow y = 2x\TAG{e:test8}
\end{gather*}
\verb+\labelcref{e:test8,e:test7}+ yields `\labelcref{e:test8,e:test7}', while \verb+\labelcref{e:test7,e:test8}+ yields `\labelcref{e:test7,e:test8}' \ding{51}

\begin{equation}\label{e:test9}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{gather*}
    y = x + x\\
    \Rightarrow y = 2x\TAG{e:test10}
\end{gather*}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test11}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\verb+\labelcref{e:test9,e:test11,e:test10}+ yields `\labelcref{e:test9,e:test11,e:test10}' \ding{51}

\begin{equation}\label{e:test12}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test13}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{e:test14}
    y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{gather*}
    y = x + x\\
    \Rightarrow y = 2x\TAG{e:test15}
\end{gather*}
\verb+\labelcref{e:test12,e:test14,e:test15,e:test13}+ yields `\labelcref{e:test12,e:test14,e:test15,e:test13}' \ding{51}

\begin{verbatim}
\labelcref{e:test1,e:test2,e:test3,e:test4,e:test5,e:test6,e:test7,%
           e:test8,e:test9,e:test10,e:test11,e:test12,e:test13,e:test14,e:test15}
\end{verbatim}
yields 
`\labelcref{e:test1,e:test2,e:test3,e:test4,e:test5,e:test6,e:test7,%
            e:test8,e:test9,e:test10,e:test11,e:test12,e:test13,e:test14,e:test15}' \ding{51}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible, thanks! Do you know what the problem was? Is obviously some intricacy in how cleveref works...

Comment: @jonnybolton16 I edited my answer in an attempt of adding some explanation. ;-)

Comment: Cool. _How_ LaTeX works is definitely outside of my knowledge haha

Comment: @jonnybolton16 In case you are one of those who are not just urged to use LaTeX for a few pieces of work while still in university and who will never use it again afterwards but are interested in how LaTeX works, I suggest the commented sources of LaTeX 2e - [https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e). Besides this the usenet-newsgroup comp.text.tex  and TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange are good places to ask in case you need explanation on how some snippet of TeX-code/LaTeX-code works.

Answer (score 1):

[This is really a comment, but I don't have the required reputation.]

Ulrich Diez's answer worked perfectly for me in the main body—thanks! But I encountered a few issues in the appendix, such as failure to compress many references into a range. And redefining `\theequation` to be non-numeric, e.g. `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}`, would cause compilation errors.

**Fix:** I believe changing the two instances of `[equation][\theequation][]` to `[equation][\arabic{equation}][\cref@result]` fixes both of these issues.

- Changing `[]` to `[\cref@result]` fixes the sorting issue.
- Changing `\theequation` to `\arabic{equation}` fixes the issue caused by redefining `\theequation`.