# Beamer \href not working

Tags: tables, beamer, href

I am having troubles getting the `\href` to work. Below is the `MWE` where I am trying to include in the caption of the table on one slide the hyperref to another slide. It looks clickable in the pdf version but does not execute the jump. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
\documentclass [10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{6pt}{11pt}\selectfont}
 \definecolor{beaublue}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.9}
 
 \begin{document}
 
 
% Short table
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample Characteristics}
\begin{center}
\begin{table} [!tbh]
\caption{Baseline Balance (\href{Baselinefull}{\blue{Full Table}})}
\centering
\tiny
\scalebox{0.78}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\toprule
& \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Treatment} & \textbf{t-test Difference}\\ & \textbf{(N=754)} & \textbf{(N=771)} & \textbf{(1)-(2)}\\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\toprule
Female  & 0.82  & 0.81  & 0.00\\
& (0.01) & (0.01)\\
\midrule
Age & 35.59 & 36.37 & -0.78\\
& (0.46) &  (0.54)\\
\midrule
Belongs to scheduled/backward   & 0.47  & 0.45 & 0.02\\
caste or tribe  & (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
\midrule
Married &   0.81 & 0.85 & -0.05**\\
& (0.01) &  (0.01)\\
\midrule
Hindu & 0.76 &  0.78 &  -0.02\\
& (0.02)     & (0.02)\\
\midrule
Household members & 5.01 &  4.97 &  0.04\\
& (0.08) &  (0.09)\\
\midrule
Unemployed &    0.33 & 0.32 & 0.01\\
& (0.02)     & (0.027)\\
\midrule
No education & 0.22 & 0.22 & 0.00\\
& (0.02)    & (0.02)    \\
\midrule
Past-month income & 17968.91 & 13262.10 & 4706.80\\
& (3941.90) & (1754.74)\\
\midrule
Past-month savings & 7381.29 & 7933.16 & -551.87\\
& (1211.84) & (1168.38)\\
\midrule
Past-month temptation spending (INR) &  128.06 &    126.14 & 1.92\\
& (23.11) & (16.84) \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[01ex]
F-test of joint significance (F-stat) & & & 0.765\\
\midrule
\addlinespace[1ex]
F-test, number of observations & & & 1525\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

% Full Table
\begin{frame}
\label{Baselinefull}
\frametitle{Baseline Balance Full Table}
\begin{center}
\begin{table} [!tbh]
\caption{Baseline Balance Full Table}
\centering
\tiny
\scalebox{0.5}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\toprule
& \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Treatment} & \textbf{t-test Difference}\\ & \textbf{(N=754)} & \textbf{(N=771)} & \textbf{(1)-(2)}\\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\toprule
Female  & 0.82  & 0.81  & 0.00\\
& (0.01) & (0.01)\\
\midrule
Age & 35.59 & 36.37 & -0.78\\
& (0.46) &  (0.54)\\
\midrule
Belongs to scheduled/backward   & 0.47  & 0.45 & 0.02\\
caste or tribe  & (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
\midrule
Married &   0.81 & 0.85 & -0.05**\\
& (0.01) &  (0.01)\\
\midrule
Hindu & 0.76 &  0.78 &  -0.02\\
& (0.02)     & (0.02)\\
\midrule
Household members & 5.01 &  4.97 &  0.04\\
& (0.08) &  (0.09)\\
\midrule
Unemployed &    0.33 & 0.32 & 0.01\\
& (0.02)     & (0.027)\\
\midrule
No education & 0.22 & 0.22 & 0.00\\
& (0.02)    & (0.02)    \\
\midrule
Completed primary education & 0.20  & 0.21  & 0.00\\
& (0.02)    & (0.01)    \\
\midrule
Completed secondary education & 0.36 &  0.39 &  -0.03\\
& (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
\midrule
Completed tertiary education &  0.21 &  0.19 &  0.02\\
& (0.02)     & (0.01)\\
\midrule
Past-month income & 17968.91 & 13262.10 & 4706.80\\
& (3941.90) & (1754.74)\\
\midrule
Past-month savings & 7381.29 & 7933.16 & -551.87\\
& (1211.84) & (1168.38)\\
\midrule
Past-month temptation spending (INR) &  128.06 &    126.14 & 1.92\\
& (23.11) & (16.84) \\
\midrule
Temptation index &  1.47 &  1.44 &  0.03\\
& (0.03) &  (0.02)\\
\midrule
Self-efficacy index & 6.12 &    6.15 &  -0.03\\
& (0.09)    & (0.09)    \\
\midrule
Female empowerment index &  0.02 &  -0.02 & 0.04\\
& (0.04) &  (0.04)\\
\midrule
Outstanding debt & 8810.23  & 10651.75 & -1841.52\\
& (1994.31) & (2736.34)\\
\midrule
Past-month household expenditures  & 5088.60    & 5491.69   & -403.09\\
(for selected goods) & (398.14) & (435.67)\\
\midrule
Resilience index &  0.27 & 0.28 & -0.01\\
& (0.02) &  (0.02)\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[01ex]
F-test of joint significance (F-stat) & & & 0.765\\
\midrule
\addlinespace[1ex]
F-test, number of observations & & & 1525\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
 
 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: \href is not for internal links. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553769/2388

Comment: Oh yes, thank you!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.